# PHP 7.2 OAUTH 2.0.2 fail to load extension

Tags: php, oauth

Using PHP 7.2.2 64bit NTS and PHP_oauth.dll (7.1 Non Thread Safe (NTS) x64)

Running extension from IIS in Windows Server 2008 R2 (64bit NTS) the following error occurs:-

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'oauth' (tried: C:\php\ext\oauth (The specified module could not be found.), C:\php\ext\php_oauth.dll (The specified procedure could not be found.
>   )) in Unknown on line 0

Although all other extensions load fine.

Running `php -m` directly from the command prompt on both Windows 2008 R2 and also Windows 10 the following error occurs:

> The procedure entry point spprintf could not be located in the dynamic link library c:\php\ext\php_oauth.dll

Answer (score 1):

Found that Oauth 2.0.2. doesn't seem to support PHP 7.2 yet.

Reverted back to 7.1